# How can I setup an ssh server on my ADSL+WiFi router?

Tags: ssh

My ISP provides me with an adsl+wifi router, when I try to ssh into it I get the following response

> ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.1 port 22: No route to host

How can I setup an ssh server on my router so that I can make some more manual configurations. Please know that I can telnet into the router though.

Comment: Not much info here... Alot of ISP provided routers are locked down for home users. I assume that 192.168.1.1 you got from the web page of the ADSL router? If there isn't an SSH option on the page, you can't telnet to port 21 (22 is SSH), and if you search google for your exact model and SSH Access - then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If the router doesn't have built-in `ssh` capabilities, which is more than likely the case, you could consider changing your firmware.

There are third party firmware projects that may provide you with a firmware image for your particular router.  These are generally more complex that the manufacturer's firmware and provide additional services such as `ssh`.  You'll need to check on the project websites to see if your device is supported.

Have a look at projects such as:

- [openWRT](https://openwrt.org/)
- [DD-WRT](https://secure.dd-wrt.com/site/)

Also, the Wikipedia's [list of firmware projects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wireless_router_firmware_projects).